# Routing traffic to outside Kubernetes using Traefik Ingress Controller

Tags: networking, kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, upstream-branch

I am using Traefik as ingress controller for my Kubernetes cluster.
It is working fine, and as expected for all of the use-cases except one.

I have few services/applications, all serving on the same URL/Host, but on a different path.
Till now all the applications were deployed on EC2-VMs, behind an ALB, and routing rules were written in ALB.

Now I have migrated some applications to Kubernetes, and some are still deployed behind the ALB. I want all traffic to be served through traefik only, and traefik should route to applications inside Kubernetes and outside Kubernetes based on path rules.

I want to point my URL to traefik and have a rule something like(such that I can define one upstream as URL):

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: tcp-80
        path: /abc
      - backend:
          serviceName: xyz-service
          servicePort: tcp-80
        path: /xyz
      - backend:
          serviceName: 12345-alb-url.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com ##I am not sure what the key will be
          servicePort: tcp-80
        path: /123
```

Is this possible with traefik? I tried searching on traefik docs, and on google but couldn't find any relevant solution.

Comment: Try it with a Headless mode service. I think it worked the last time I tried it but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `ExternalName`-type Service for services deployed out of the cluster and forward traffic to the Service in the Ingress. See [Type ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)
.